# Manipulation specific string c#

Tags: c#, .net, string

I have this string

```
%1111_Ç2222_Ç3333_
```

and I want remove the characters between the first and second _

```
Ç2222_
```

What is the best way to do this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you try _anything_ so far? Not a hard problem at all.. Use methods like `String.Split`, `String.IndexOf` and `String.Substring`.. Always show your effort first, so people might show theirs. Read [FAQ], [help] and [ask]

Comment: pls post an attempt...

Comment: `What is the best way to do this?`..The best way is to try to write some code!

Comment: "I want remove the characters between the first and second `_`" What happened to `%1111` then?

Comment: What is the desired result, `%1111_Ç3333_`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe you want to go into this direction, but your question is not that clear...

```
string sIn = "%1111_Ç2222_Ç3333_";
string sOut = string.Join("_", sIn.Split('_').Where((x, index) => index != 1));
```

Comment: Thank you!
Not explained myself well.

I want the string sOut like: Ç2222_

Catching the first Ç and second _

THANK YOU